# How to export this from mySQL using SQL or PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table below in mySQL with thousands of rows. If you notice 1, 2, 3 token are the same but the 3rd token has a different IP.

```
token                                  ip
4aa1813449465a6ec1fc82e0ef09e2b1       2.17.58.126
4aa1813449465a6ec1fc82e0ef09e2b1       2.17.58.126
4aa1813449465a6ec1fc82e0ef09e2b1       94.71.213.235
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e       63.24.23.129
```

My question is how can I end up with removing all duplicates rows ( token + ip ) ending with this

```
token                                  ip
4aa1813449465a6ec1fc82e0ef09e2b1       2.17.58.126
4aa1813449465a6ec1fc82e0ef09e2b1       94.71.213.235
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e       63.24.23.129
```

Comment: Do you want to select or delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM <table>;
```

To create a new cleaned up table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * INTO <newtable> FROM <table>;
```

To clean up the table inline you would need to have a unique primary key, you cannot 'deduplicate' completely identical rows since you cannot target the individual duplicates.

Comment: Will this work if instead of the * write token, ip ?

Comment: If those are the only 2 fields it's identical - `*` just means 'all available fields'.